# QTableView not updated when using a lineEdit filtering

Tags: python-3.x, pyqt5, qsortfilterproxymodel

I have a QtableView (PyQt5) linked to a proxyModel to allow filtering with a lineEdit. The table view is not updated when the text is changed, could you see why ?

```
class mainWindow(QtWidgets.QMainWindow):
    def __init__(self, data, headers, parent=None):
            # non necessary stuff
        self._model = myTableModel(data, headers)

        self._proxyModel = myProxyModel()    
        self._proxyModel.setSourceModel(self._model)
        self.tableView.setModel(self._proxyModel)

        self.lineEdit.textChanged.connect(self.on_changed_text)

    def on_changed_text(self, value):
        self._proxyModel.filterString = str(value)  

class myProxyModel(QtCore.QSortFilterProxyModel):
    def __init__(self, parent=None):
        super(myProxyModel, self).__init__(parent)
        self.filterString = ""

    def filterAcceptsRow(self, sourceRow, parent=None):
        source_model = self.sourceModel()

            # Looking over the whole table to match the filterString
        for col in range(source_model.columnCount()):
            tested_index = source_model.index(sourceRow, col)
            if self.filterString in str(tested_index.data()):
                return True
        return False
```

When I modify the filterString directly in the **init**() of myProxyModel, the filtering works but it doesn't when the text is updated in the line edit.

Thanks !

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I think you need to call `invalidateFilter`, something like:

```
def on_changed_text(self, value):
    self._proxyModel.filterString = str(value)
    self._proxyModel.invalidateFilter()
```

so the filter knows that the method has been changed.  This triggers it to trigger the View to update.